# Flatlist not sorting properly after re render

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I have a flatlist of data that I am trying to sort in order based on their date. When the application first starts the list is correct however if the user adds an event and then gives it a time it will not sort it into the rest of the list, only above items that don't have a date or were also inputted during the current session. Then if I refresh with that exact data it will be placed properly into the list.

I am unsure why the flatlist is not re-rendering properly while the user is in an active session but works perfectly upon refresh of the application.

My flatlist-

```
render() {
    const items = _.sortBy(this.props.todos, (item) => {
      return item.date;
    });
    return (
      <View style={{ height: HEIGHT }}>
          <AddTodo
            textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
            addNewTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}
            textInput={this.state.textInput}
          />
          <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <FlatList
              data={items}
              extraData={this.state}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                  <TodoItem
                    todoItem={item}
                    deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Same component trying without items produces same result-

```
<View style={{ height: HEIGHT }}>
          <AddTodo
            textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
            addNewTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}
            textInput={this.state.textInput}
          />
          <View style={styles.listContainer}>
            <FlatList
              data={_.sortBy(this.props.todos, (item) => {
                return item.date;
              })}
              extraData={this.props.todos}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                  <TodoItem
                    todoItem={item}
                    deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
```

Since items are in the render method why would it not properly re-sort the entire list and only the ones without dates and in the current user session?

I can provide more code if necessary, but I figured the problem has to be something with my flatlist.

Answer (score 0):

The FlatList is a Pure Component as mentioned in the docs !.What that means is after a initial render it checks for the props change to re render the list.From looking your code try to give `extraData={items}`.

**EDIT:**

From the question asked in comments,you can sort the items before setting to the state and just render using data in FlatList.Also remember to sort the data while setting for first time.Here is a working [Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/flatlist-sorted)

Comment: I tried this and it still has the same issue as with `extraDate={this.state}`

Comment: Can you sort the items and set it to state?

Comment: How would you go about doing that? I created items in the state and tried to call setState after items are sorted but am now getting an invariant violation of maximum depth exceeded.

Comment: I don't think it will work because the date won't be available once the event is added. It will be done at a later time. So the way you instantly have the numbers when it is created I cannot replicate for my application.

Comment: How are you sorting the items initially?.You cannot sort a list of item without some order.

Comment: this.props.todos is all of the added todos. The first todo added will be first on a list and it will move like that. I am doing the sorting in the flatlist component with the items const and then passing that in as the data.

Comment: Correct me here...You will be having some list of todo's and the new todo is appended at the end of list right?.Why is there a need to sort the list here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200172/discussion-between-thakur-karthik-and-goolius-boozler).

Comment: Yes so the new item will then be placed at the list. But say you then give that item a date that is before other items in the list. I want it to automatically move up in the list. If I reload the application it will do this but in the current session it will only be able to move in front of other todos that were added in the current session or ones that did not have any date

Answer (score 0):

You should move the sorting logic of your app to the renderItem method. I'd also set this.props.todos as extraData, so that the FlatList will trigger a rerender when the data changes.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ height: HEIGHT }}>
      <AddTodo
        textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
        addNewTodo={this.addTodo.bind(this)}
        textInput={this.state.textInput}
      />
    <View style={styles.listContainer}>
      <FlatList
        data={items.sortBy(this.props.todos, item => item.date)}
        extraData={this.props.todos}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TodoItem
              todoItem={item}
              deleteTodo={() => this.props.removeTodo(item)}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
)}
```